# Laravel View error query Property does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel, function

I have this function in my controller :

```
 public function edit(funcionario $item){
     $ferias = feria::join ('funcionarios','funcionarios.id','=', 'ferias.id_funcionario')
     ->where( 'ferias.id_funcionario', '=', $item->id)
     ->get(['ferias.id_funcionario', 'ferias.n_ferias_disponiveis', 'funcionarios.id']);
    return view('painel-admin.utilizadores.edit', ['item' => $item, 'ferias' => $ferias]);   
 }
```

The "Item" work perfectly but "ferias" not.

I want to show the values ​​that are inside the vacation field.
**strong text**
value="{{$ferias}}" This it work and show this :

```
 [{"id_funcionario":23,"n_ferias_disponiveis":22,"id":23}]
```

but i try this value="{{$ferias->n_ferias_disponiveis}}" show this error :

Property [n_ferias_disponiveis] does not exist on this collection instance

Comment: It is collection, you can tell by square brackets that hold curly bracket item. You would access as `$ferias[0]->n_ferias_disponiveis`.

Answer (score 0):

return value in collection, so you have to make a foreach loop to get the particular one field...

```
foreach($ferias as $feria)
{
    $name = $feria->n_ferias_disponiveis;
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?